# Emulator Nexus4 API 17 has no builtin Email client

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
Android Studio 0.4.6
```

Hello,

I am creating an App that will use the email client. However, having created a Nexus4 emulator targeting Jelly Bean 4.2.2. I see there is no email client. Is this normal behavior?

I have tried going through the settings, but cannot find any indication that there exists an Email client.

Just a followup question. If I wanted to install gmail email client, is that possible on an emulator? As there is no google play store App.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its Possible to install Any app On Emulator.
But You need that Apk file..

First in your Emulator setting(settings > application Manager or Setting > Security) You need to enable.
Allow Unknown Sources Then You can Install any `.apk` file..
like this

[image: You will seed this option At Settings in Emulator]

Then Can Download [Play store](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/01/download-latest-google-play-store-4-4-22/) 
Or You can Download [Gmail](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/01/08/apk-download-gmail-4-7-2-update-adds-promised-auto-show-images-feature/)
From those Links at bottom you will have download option. download the `.apk` file

After Downloading You need to Push the file to Emulator .. and browse it and install
or else [follow this](http://blog.kerul.net/2012/08/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android.html) **To install that application directly**..
 OR [Refer this](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator) to install any `apk` file to Emulator.

This is the only process which works..

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Stock android does not come with Gmail. It's a proprietary package that is not installed on emulators. You'll need to install an email app manually by uploading an apk via adb or test on a real device.